# How a thread can call notify when other thread has acquired lock on same instance with Wait() call?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

My biggest confusion is When one thread has acquired lock on object and suppose we have one  condition which has forced to call wait() (So thread will wait until get notify), then how come other thread of same instance can call notify as  first thread already has possessed lock on instance. Below problem similar to producer consumer ,

```
 Class ABC{
    void getA(){
    synchronised(this){
         while(xyz){
          wait();
        }
        notify();
      }
    }   

    void getB(){
    synchronised(this){
         while(abc){
          wait()
        }
       notify();
      }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Calling `wait()` releases the lock.

Comment: Thanks, So when notify get called by another thread , Thread which in wait mode will start execution from where it is stuck ? it will start execution again ?

Comment: Yes, at which point it again holds the lock (of course it has to wait that the thread that called `notify()` releases it first).

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for clarifying , making things easy for me